# ASP.NET Response.Redirect() doesn't work without try/catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, exception, response.redirect

I have a trouble, which I didn't get earlier with the `ASP.NET`. I can't redirect to the some location with the method `Response.Redirect()`

I've read another topics and may tell you, what exactly I have tried:

- I don't use `Response.Redirect()` in `try/catch` block, which may cause an `ThreadAbortException` ( but if you try to ignore this exception - you must be redirected, even in this case I can't redirect )
- I've tried to use `Boolean` values , where using them as a flag at the end of `Page_Load()` method to make a redirection
- I've tried to use even the JS-call with the `location` property, but ASP.NET ignores it... As I see I could call any function in JS and it will be ignored
- Tried to set to the `false` the value of the second parameter of method `Response.Redirect()`

I shall paste `ONLY` one of the variants, because as I wrote upper I tried different ways, but no success.

Code: http://ideone.com/Y8Fwpt

Redirect on `58th` line doesn't work even there is a handler for the `ThreadAbortException`. Calling JS-scenario on `62nd` line - ignores too.

Even if I remove `try/catch block` - nothing will change.

Please, help me to fix this issue!

Comment: Might need to use `Request` rather than `Response`.

Comment: @TiesonT. `Request` class doesn't have the `Redirect()` method.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct. I thought I was using `Request` in a project, but it was `Response`. Do you have anything in, say, the Global.asax that might be appending something to the output stream?

Comment: @TiesonT. No, I don't, you could download my project here (vs2010 requires): http://81.176.229.82/WebApplication1.zip , will be very pleased if you help me

Comment: Does the request complete successfully? Have you checked with Firebug / Chrome

Comment: @RLT request isn't completing it does go to the `ThreadAbortException` always, if to remove try/catch block it will be idling and no more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make the redirect work if I removed the `onclick()` you have on the login form - I think your query string isn't coming across correctly, so you wind up just doing a quick page refresh. So, I would make two suggestions:

**One**, remove all the script & Ajax stuff you're trying to do, and get it working with normal postbacks first - then you can go back and try the async stuff.

**Two**, I wouldn't mess with creating your own cookies at this point - the MySQLConnector library has `Membership` and `Role` providers you can use that are built to connect to MySQL databases.

In a nutshell, the idiom I hold near and dear when I'm developing is "do the simplest thing that works," which in this case is just "classic" ASP.NET postbacks...

HTH.

Comment: thanks for a great answer... I'm using postbacks now, but I'm displeased with this problem... I wanted to make GET-queries recursively on one page for monitoring statuses and want to be independent from page refresh. Seems to be, that problem was around the AJAX.

Comment: @OlegOrlov You still can, although I have to say that a partial-page refresh is more work than it should be in WebForms, due to the ViewState mechanism. One option that might work is to build the page such that the page request loads an `UpdatePanel` with whatever statuses exist at that moment in time, and then fetch the new "current" statuses at pre-defined intervals.